# Надо что-то сделать с меткой [двумерный]

Tags: предложение, метки

На сайте есть метка [двумерный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9) (без описания). На данный момент она используется на 3 вопросах и только вместе с меткой [массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b). Может стоит превратит её в [двумерные-массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b) и убрать из всех вопросов с ней метку [массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b)? Тем более, что метка [2d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2d) у нас уже есть.

Answer (score 3):

На enSO есть метка [multidimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/multidimensional-array/synonyms) с достаточным количеством синонимов, где есть и двумерный массив. Наверное, нам тоже стоит такую создать, чтобы не обобщать всё единственной меткой [массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b).

Упомянутые вопросы со сдвоенными метками "массивы" и "двумерный" появились скорее всего из-за ввода словосочетания "двумерный массив". В таком виде в поле ввода меток это воспринимается как две отдельные метки, одна из которых "массив" была заменена на "массивы" (из-за существующего синонима).

Сейчас добавил метку [двумерный-массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2) для этих вопросов. В дальнейшем это можно делать без привлечения модератора и создания отдельного вопроса на Мете.